# Send bitmap parameter to another xaml page

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.1 , i have a ListView. My list is populated with an ObservableColection of Pictures. In class Pictures i have pictureName , and bitmapImage.
In ListView_Item_Click , i want to click a Picture and send it to another xaml page.

```cs
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img = ((Picture)e.ClickedItem).Image;//imi selectez imaginea care doresc!!
var image = new Image();
image.Source = img;
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), image);  in mainpage.xaml.cs
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't pass *BitmapImage* as a parameter of *Frame.Navigate* - it's not serializable and there will be a problem with *SuspensionManager* or *Resuming/Suspending* events.

The solution depends on your images - where to they come from - if it's a file, then you can just pass a path to that file and then in *OnNavigated* (for example), set the *ImageSource* from file.

Other method may be to set *BitmapImage* in target page, before it's navigated to - for example use *static* property:

```cs
public class TargetPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static BitmapImage bmpImage;
    public static BitmapImage BmpImage
    {
        get { return bmpImage; }
        set { bmpImage = value; RaisePropertyChanged("BmpImage"); }
    }
    // rest of the code
```

Then you can just set the image before navigating:

```cs
TargetPage.BmpImage = img;
Frame.Navigate(typeof(TargetPage));
```

Also you should remember about *Suspending* and *Resuming* events and the case when your app is being terminated while it's *Suspended*. In every case you should somehow remember the source of the image - using *SuspensionManager*, *PageState*, *Settings* or other method.